# How I get the value of key using xPath expression

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to write a XPath expression to evaluate if the value of key 'ErrorCode' = -3025 at XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <esb:esb-header xmlns:esb="http://schemas.company.com/soa/esb">
    <esb:params>
      <esb:param>
        <esb:param-name>ErrorCode</esb:param-name>
        <esb:param-value>-3025</esb:param-value>
      </esb:param>
    </esb:params>
  </esb:esb-header>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Note that the elements has prefix.

Answer (score 0):

XPath 2.0:

```
/*:Envelope/*:esb-header/*:params/*:param[*:param-name='ErrorCode' and *:param-value='-3025']
```

For XPath 1.0, you can use `local-name()` instead (yuck):

```
/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='esb-header']/*[local-name()='params']/*[local-name()='param'][*[local-name()='param-name']='ErrorCode' and *[local-name()='param-value']='-3025']
```

If you have a way to declare those namespaces, it would be much easier in 1.0 to use prefixes instead of `local-name()`.

Also, you can wrap the whole path in `boolean()` (XPath 1.0/2.0) or `exists()` (XPath 2.0) to return either `true` or `false`.